# How can i persist my logs/data to local filesystem in docker

Tags: docker, dockerhub

have an application running inside docker container. the application writes log messages into local log files. how can i make the log file persistent in case the docker container stops or crashes?

Since the container are run time entity ,when i stop the image my logs/data is gone.

Thanks,
Sohan

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this using docker volumes:

https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

For example:

```
docker run -v /var/log/docker:/var/log your-image
```

will mount the log directory on your local file system.  You can also get much fancier, creating containers just for data.  It's all explained in the above link.

Comment: How do I achieve this within a compose file? Will `volumes` suffice?

Comment: Worth noting that the paths specified must be absolute paths.