# How to keep log files after deleting docker containers?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I want to collect docker container logs, By default, log files will be deleted when removing container. It cause several logs lost each time i update my service. How to keep log files after removing containers?
Or, Is there another way to collect all logs from containers without losing？

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can i persist my logs/data to local filesystem in docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26677860/how-can-i-persist-my-logs-data-to-local-filesystem-in-docker)

Comment: Do you mean the docker logs (that you can see using `docker logs <container>` or logs saved in the file system in the container?

Comment: In my option,docker service's log,will not be deleted when update docker service——the log will be delete when the container be delete,but updateing service will not delete old container. If you mean to the app's log,such as python,java, use `-v` to mapping to local filesystem,or,use other distributed log solution,in python,`HttpHandler`  may be useful.

Comment: You tagged this with "kubernetes"; there's a page in the Kubernetes documentation discussing [Logging Architecture](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/).  Conceptually you could do similar things (like running a system-level fluentd) with plain Docker, though the mechanics will be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be two situations:

- If your logs are the stdout or stderr, you can save them before removing the container:

```sh
docker logs CONTAINER_ID > container.log
```

- If your logs are stored in some files, in this case, you can copy them out or mount a directory for them while running the container:

```sh
# Copy the logs out to the host
docker copy CONTAINER_ID:/path/to/your/log_file /host/path/to/store

# Mount a directory for them
docker run -d \
-v /host/path/to/store/logs:/container/path/stored/logs \
your-image
```

Comment: Stdout/err logs, I just want docker do not delete the log files. Because container is recreate by CI/CD., no man work here.

Comment: yeah, maybe you should add the step of saving your logs before removing containers into the CI/CD workflows